# unset javascript array for

Tags: javascript, unset, splice

I've been trying at this for hours now and I thought it would be really simple;

Using javascript I basically want to iterate through an array, get the current value of the index and then unset this value from the array. I've found splice() is supposed to work for this however I don't seem to be able to empty the array, there is always one value left on the arrary

```
var filtered = array("up", "down", "left");
 function resetTags(){
       var length = filtered.length;

       for(i=0; i <= length; i++){
            filtered.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT::**

I'll try to explain in a bit more detail:

I'm basically trying to keep track of a listed of  selected class values which are obtained
from when an item is clicked:
     var filtered = array();

```
    jQuery("li a").click(function () {
     tag = jQuery(this).text();
     addFiltered(tag);
});

 function addFiltered(param){
      var inArray =  jQuery.inArray(param,filtered);
      if(inArray > -1){
        //param is in array, so we want to remove it from the filtered array 
            filtered.splice(index, 1);
        });

        }else{
         //param isn't in array, so we want to add it to the array 
            filtered.splice(0, 0, param);
        });
        }


    }
```

Comment: I just ran the above and don't get any values left on the array. I did change array() to ["up", "down", "left"] so it might be something that your function array() is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to empty the array, set it to be an empty array directly:

```
filtered = [];
```

If you want to use the values before emptying the array, simply iterate before that without removing values and clear it when you are done.

What do you stand to gain by messing with convoluted solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're incrementing. Have you tried decrementing?

```
var filtered = new Array("up", "down", "left");

function resetTags(){
   var length = filtered.length;

   for(i = length; i >= 0; i--){
        filtered.splice(i,1);
   }
}
```

This should make sure the final element is spliced.

Answer (score 0):

the array was defined incorrectly. That is why the code didn't excute

```
 var filtered = ["up", "down", "left"];
     function resetTags(){
           var length = filtered.length;

           for(i=0; i <= length; i++){
                filtered.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var filtered = ["up", "down", "left"];`
is the same with `var filtered = array("up", "down", "left");`

Answer (score 0):

To remove items one by one:

> var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
>
> while (a.length > 0 ) {
>       a.splice(0,1);
>        }

http://jsfiddle.net/89hkH/

Answer (score 0):

> I basically want to iterate through an array, get the current value
>   of the index and then unset this value from the array.

```
for(i=0; i <= length; i++){
            filtered.splice(i,1);
        }
```

I don't think you are clearly defining (or perhaps don't know), what you're trying to do.

Are you trying to write a `pop(n)` method such that:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]
var result = pop(3, a)
result == [ 1, 2, 4]
```

Or are you just trying to walk an array and get the first element off every time? If so, you're doing it wrong. That's just a [shift()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)

```
 var filtered = ["up", "down", "left"]
 for(i = 0 ; i<= filtered.length; i++)
    {
       alert(filtered);
       filtered.shift();
       alert(filtered);          
    }
```